# How can I prove my travel history if I've lost my passport?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, history

I have applied for a US visitor visa, and the visa officer raised the question about my history of travelled countries. Because I have lost my passport, I was not able to prove that I have travelled so many countries. So can anyone guide me on how to get our old passport details wherever we have visited through any government body which can be acceptable by visa officer? Please help me so I can reapply for USA visa.

Comment: It's probably helpful to know your nationality, since different countries might make different provisions. If you were refused a visa, we also need to know exactly what grounds were given for the refusal. (Many people in situations similar to yours believe they were rejected for some reason, when the refusal letter shows that there was a completely different reason.)

Comment: It isn't a government record, but were the flights you took recorded in airline mileage account(s)? I try to make sure every flight I take is recorded somewhere where I can recover them so I can answer days-in-the-country questions on tax filings accurately; passport stamps are really unreliable. I would echo, however, that the things they ask you about at interviews (particularly US interviews, which are pro forma legal requirements) aren't always greatly relavent to the reasons for a rejection.

Comment: I would recommend credit card and banking account statements showing charges and ATM withdrawals.

Answer (score 9):

Honesty I do not think it is possible and even a passport does not record all movements between any countries. Some countries do not use exit stamps, some no entry stamps and some do it on pieces of paper which you hold onto while there and hand back on exit.

Many countries keep their own records but those are only from a single point-of-view. For example, in Ecuador we con obtain our *Cerficado Migratorio* which is a list of all times a person has entered and exited the country. So, they know when I left and came back - even *across passport changes* - but they do not know from where or to where. Since my passport is Canadian, *almost* all  lines in the report says that I arrived from Canada, although it does show the first immediate transit to another Andean Community nation, possibly because of some information accord. For example, when I traveled to Bolivia from Ecuador via Peru, my record says that I went to Peru. Apparently, they only share entry and not exit because, coming back on the same route it says that I came from Canada.

You would have to contact immigration offices of every country you visited to create a travel history. Even so, I am sure many countries do not keep records, do not keep them for longer than a certain period and may not have electronic record-keeping until some years ago, so would not be able to retrieve your records quickly, assuming they still exit.